# shell variable not keeping value

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pipeline, subshell

I have 3 lines in file `/root/backuplist.txt`.

The first `echo` prints perfectly, but the last one prints an empty line; I'm not sure why. Somehow, the `$DIRS` value is getting unset.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /root/backuplist.txt |
while read line
do
  DIRS+="$line "
  echo $DIRS
done

echo $DIRS
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring `DIRS` at the very top of your script (before `cat`)?

Comment: Yes. If I do, DIRS="hi" then the last echo command prints only "hi"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is use of pipe here, which is **forking a sub-shell** for your `while` loop and thus changes to `DIRS` are being made in the child shell that are not visible in the parent shell. Besides `cat` is unnecessary here.

Have it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
   DIRS+="$line "
   echo "$DIRS"
done < /root/backuplist.txt

echo "$DIRS"
```

Comment: Awesome! works great!